# Failing to delete registry key

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on a writing a VBScript and I have no experience with VBS.  I can do this with a command line with no problem, however, it needs to be in VBS.

The script I'm working on checks to see if 2 registry keys exist, and if so, deletes a third key.  I've been looking around on the net and found some code that works for what I want to do.  My issue is on the delete RegKey code.  I found this code which works fine, however, if I modify it to point to a different location, it doesn't work.

Here is the code I found and if I put a key in the registry, it deletes it just fine.

Created this key:  HKCU\Software\Test

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001 

strComputer = "."
strKeyPath = "Software\Test" 

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv") 

DeleteSubkeys HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeypath 

Sub DeleteSubkeys(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath) 
    objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys 

    If IsArray(arrSubkeys) Then 
        For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
            DeleteSubkeys HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey 
        Next 
    End If 

    objRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath 
End Sub
```

But if I change the code to this, it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Created this key:  HKLM\Software\Test

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002 

strComputer = "."
strKeyPath = "Software\Test" 

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv") 

DeleteSubkeys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeypath 

Sub DeleteSubkeys(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath) 
    objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys 

    If IsArray(arrSubkeys) Then 
        For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
            DeleteSubkeys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey 
        Next 
    End If 

    objRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath 
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely you don't have the required permissions to delete keys in HKLM. The WMI registry methods fail silently. Errors are indicated via their return code, so check that: `rc = objRegistry.DeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath) : WScript.Echo rc`

Comment: Thanks, I did that and I get a prompt with "5".  Not sure what that means...  I also changed the Set objRegistry to this and it gives me a "5" also.  

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

Comment: A return code of 5 means "access denied". Check the permissions on the key from which you want to delete your new subkey.